# I want to display (the most popular posts for today) in wordpress and this list should be updated automatically every day

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I did display the most popular posts in my website using a function but the problem is that this function display the most popular posts for all time and I don't want this.

I want to display (the most popular posts for today)and this list should be updated automatically every day.

Note that I don't want to use plugins

THis is in functions.php

```
<?php //fucntion to sort posts bade in thier views.
$args_views = array(  'posts_per_page'  => 6,  /* get 4 posts, or set -1 for all */
                'orderby'      => 'meta_value',  /* this will look at the meta_key you set below */
                'meta_key'     => 'post_views_count',
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_status'  => 'publish'
            );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $mypost ) {
    /* do things here */
}
?>
```

and this is my query in index.php

```
<div class="container">
    <?php query_posts($args_views);?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="archive-thumbnail" class="thumbnail">
                <div class=" <?php if ( has_catch_that_image() ) { ?>archive-body <?php } ?>">
                  <div id="archive-img"><img class="media-object-sp" src="<?php echo has_catch_that_image(); ?>" alt="..."></div>
                  <h4 id="archive-thumbnail-title" style="color:#337ab7;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                  <p id="archive-thumbnail-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                  <p class="text-muted"> by: <?php the_author(); ?> | before<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ''; ?></p></div>

            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

and this is in Snigle.php

```
    <?php // this is to count the views
 setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: I update the question with the function that I use to display the most popular posts. See again

Comment: There is no built-in concept of "popular posts" in WordPress. You'll need to create some kind of post view counter in order to achieve this, unless everything is solely based on comments (which is probably not the best idea)

Comment: Ammm, I do have function to display the most popular posts based in views, see the update again :)

Comment: In order to know which post was most popular today - you'll need to know when each post was viewed as opposed to just a counter. Or alternatively you could reset all the view counts every day (making your current code work), but not taking different time zones into consideration, nor will you be able to see which post was most popular on specific dates.

Comment: Resting the views every day seems good idea. Do you have any idea how to do it? because my PHP knowledge is limited

Comment: Where are you? Any help guys?

Comment: Could you please update your code above with the `setPostViews()` function code ?

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: @AbbasAleid Please provide the definition of the function `setPostViews( )` here so, someone can help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a WordPress CRON job to reset the post view counts on daily basis. Please note that: All the view counts will be deleted on daily basis and you can't get those back.

Sample code for setting up CRON and resetting the view counts:

```
// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'subh_daily_cron_action' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'subh_daily_cron_action' );
}

/**
 * Reset the post views on daily basis.
 */
function subh_reset_postview_counters() {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $args      = array(
        'numberposts'      => -1,
        'meta_key'         => $count_key,
        'post_type'        => 'post',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );

    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $postslist as $singlepost ) {
        delete_post_meta( $singlepost->ID, $count_key );
    }
}
add_action( 'subh_daily_cron_action', 'subh_reset_postview_counters' ); // Hook into that action that will fire daily.
```

Paste the above code into your current theme's `functions.php` file. Try to use Child theme if possible (this is optional though).

For more info on setting up CRON jobs through WordPress visit: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event